# Nested loops of image detection takes forever to run 100 mil times

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I'm doing some work for a thesis and have to try out some filters on various images and see if the object is detected. Everything works fine per se, but my intention was to apply 100 different degrees of each of 4 filters(contrast, blur and others) onto a frame gradually and see where it stops detecting correctly.

I would combine them, so for example first some image is imported to a frame, then I try detecting by adding "0%" contrast, "0%" blur, "0%" resize, "0%" noise, next round 1% contrast, others all 0%, then 2% contrast, others 0%, and so on up until 100% contrast. Next loop it should do the same thing but with 1% blur, 0% resize, 0% noise. Then 2% blur, 0%, 0%, and so on - all kinds of combinations.

But this means it needs to do 100^4 iterations(100 million if I want 100 degrees and 4 filters). And my current implementation of YOLOv3-320 with OpenCV performs a detection at the speed of about 0.5 seconds. This means it would take around 580 days to finish tests for just one picture.

```
def tester(depth, correct_answer):
container_a = []

for a in range(depth):
    print((a*(100/depth)))
    frame1 = apply_sepia(frame, int((a*(100/depth))))
    container_b = []

    for b in range(depth):
        frame2 = apply_blur(frame1, int((b*(100/depth))))
        container_c = []

        for c in range(depth):
            frame3 = sp_noise(frame2, int((c*(100/depth))))
            container_d = []

            for d in range(depth):
                frame4 = image_resize(frame3, int((d*(100/depth))))

                try:
                    net.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame4, 1/255, (vers, vers), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False))
                    result = postprocess(net.forward(getOutputsNames(net)))

                    if result == correct_answer:
                        container_d.append(1)
                    else:
                        container_d.append(0)

                except Exception as e:
                    container_d.append(0)

            container_c.append(container_d)

        container_b.append(container_c)

    container_a.append(container_b)

return container_a
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: Why do you need high parameter resolution throughout? You can reduce the number of iterations, by taking much larger steps initially, then evaluate when your objects are not detected, and zero in on the actual parameters.

Comment: Use something other than Python.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need a new Apple iMac Pro with 18 CPU cores to practice your multi-threading on.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the advice, I'll see if I can find some computer to at least ease the workload. @Scott Hunter I'm afraid I'm a bit too late to switch from Python, time schedule made me think Python was a great idea.

Comment: @warped Sorry; by high parameter resolution you mean why I need all four filters applied before I do a detection?

Comment: reduce the work or increase the used hardware. Most "expensive" part of your computations will be the yolo detection. This can be speeded up bedt by using a jigh end gpu, which will give you about 30ms of object detection time. Maybe you should use multiple PCs, each with such a GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will put this as an answer, to have slightly more space to illustrate my point.

I use the term 'high parameter resolution', to describe iterating over your parameter in small steps.

Suppose, your algorithm fails at 18% noise, and noise is the only thing you are varying.

Then, doing 1% increments will cause your object detection to fail in the 19th iteration of your run.

Screening with larger steps, to for instance 10%, will cause your algorithm to fail in the third iteration, when you are testing 20% noise. Then, you know that your algorithm fails between 10% and 20% noise. You could now use something like [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) and ask, if the algorithm fails above or below 15%, and after that, above or below 17.5%.

So, in this approach you run your algorithm for a total of five times, and get the same answer as in the brute-force approach.

Comment: Ah, I see, very good solution. Thank you so much for the help. :)